# How to add CCK fields to my own content type provided by my own module in D6?

Tags: 7, nodes, entities, media

**I'm creating a module which provides a new node content type.** I can extend the default node creation fields with my owns, but **I would like to add some CCK fields** too (like [CCK ImageField](http://drupal.org/project/imagefield)) by default, [**NOT manually** after enabling my module through the usual admin interface of Drupal's content type editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kpPc6.png).

So for example here is my own form in my module that provides a new content type; **this is what I would like to extend with a CCK ImageField (and later maybe add other CCK fields too)**:

```
/**
 * Implementation of hook_form()
 * @see my_test_module_for_content_types_node_info()
 */
function my_test_module_for_content_types_form($node){
    // Get metadata for this node type
    // (we use it for labeling title and body fields).
    // We defined this in seat_reservation_node_info()
    $type = node_get_types('type', $node);

    $form['title'] = array(
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => check_plain($type->title_label),
      '#required' => TRUE,
      '#default_value' => $node->title,
      '#weight' => -5,
      '#maxlength' => 255,
    );

    $form['body_filter']['body'] = array(
      '#type' => 'textarea',
      '#title' => check_plain($type->body_label),
      '#required' => TRUE,
      '#default_value' => $node->body,
      '#weight' => 7,
    );

    $form['body_filter']['filter'] = filter_form($node->format);

    $form['test_blabla'] = array(
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => t('This is my test field!!'),
      '#required' => TRUE,
      '#default_value' => isset($node->test_field) ? $node->test_field : '',
      '#weight' => 5,
      '#maxlength' => 255,
    );

    return $form;
}
```